# WordPress Installation Error - Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '_add_default_theme_supports' not

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, laragon, divi

Kindly assist me to resolve this error after installing my WordPress on a live server and the local one gave me this error and warning i couldn't get the site on the local server. I'm using Laragon for the local server. Please assist. The error message I got is below.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '_add_default_theme_supports' not found or invalid function name in C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 307

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_json_file_decode()
 in C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-includes\blocks.php:238 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-includes\blocks\archives.php(119): register_block_type_from_metadata('C:\\laragon\\www\\...', Array) 
#1 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(307): register_block_core_archives('') 
#2 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) 
#3 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-includes\plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#4 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-settings.php(578): do_action('init') 
#5 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-config.php(90): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') 
#6 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') 
#7 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') 
#8 C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-admin\index.php(10): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') 
#9 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\rsbenterprise\wp-includes\blocks.php on line 238

There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

Answer (score 2):

The [wp_json_file_decode()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.9/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L4457) utility function first appeared in version 5.9 of WordPress.

Your error message points to an incomplete or somehow corrupted update from a previous WordPress version to 5.9.

A good approach to fixing this problem: go to a working version of your site, then use a migration plugin to capture the working site and migrate it to a new server.

Comment: I'm not not able to login into the old server of the previous one.

Comment: You can try doing a fresh WordPress installation, then copying in the wp-content folder from your backup, then loading your backed up database. You'll have a lot of cleanup to do, but you will probably get your site back.